# iOS - Making documents uneditable using iTunes file share

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using iTunes file share across my app. My app provides several files which can be transferred over using iTunes file share. However at the moment the user can delete, rename (basically do anything to what is inside my app which is shareable)
I want to know how to make it so the user doesn't have these privileges, I want it so all they can do is transfer the file over and thats it.

Heres the code, any help much appreciated

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"test.gif", @"test1.gif", nil];
    for (NSString *fileName in names)
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath])
        {
            NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
        }
    }
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;



    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move (copy and delete) all new files from the shared directory to a non-shared directory every time your app is run.